# How to not refer to the controllerAs name in directive

Tags: angularjs

Here is the minimal code to describe the issue. On the page, I have:

```
<div ng-controller='AController as a'>
    <div a-directive></div>
</div>
```

In js, I have:

```
app.directive("aDirective", function($compile){
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = "<h1>{{a.label}}</h1>";
            element.append($compile(template)(scope));
        }
    }
});

app.controller("AController", function($scope){
    self = this;
    self.label = "some text";
});
```

That works, but the issue is that {{a.label}}, which made the view and controller/model tightly coupled. Is there any way to get rid of that a., and not to mention the controllerAs-name in the directive code at all? (just like  what I did in the controller code)

Comment: well, this depends on what you are really intending this directive to accomplish.  In this example, the only way to decouple these directives would be to introduce a parameter, i.e. `<div a-directive label="a.label">`

Comment: also, unless there is a hidden reason you aren't showing here, you should **always** favor using `template` or `templateUrl` over a `link` with `element.append`;  any time you are using `element` you are outside angular context, and using JQuery (or JQLite, if JQuery isn't available), which just makes your code more complex.

Comment: Thanks! Agree with all the other points. The code was just to describe the coupling issue. Although it is unfortunately that there is no straightforward way to decouple like what we can do in the controllers, but the solution you showed is cool. I guess, the limitation is kind of also contributed by js itself, not just angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve this you can pass the text to display as a parameter to the directive. Something like this is the initial idea:

```
<div a-directive="a.label"></div>
```

However, I DO recommend using an alias for the controller, so I made a Plunker where you can see all of this working together with some improvements.

Check it out here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1hBSBxwSEPXoj9TULzRQ?p=preview

I would also recommend to use `template` instead of `link` and restricting the directive to an element instead of using it as attribute, since it is modifying the DOM. But yeah, you could keep improving it till the end of the times :)